# Eigenvalues of $A$ compared to $A^H$

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

How are the eigenvalues of $A^H$ related to the eigenvalues of $A$?

Here $A^H$ is the conjugate transpose of $A$

Comment: There's a bug with my account that is preventing me from upvoting answers! :( I don't know how to resolve that issue...

Comment: You can contact moderators via team+math@stackexchange.com with account problems.

Comment: Yup I just did, thanks.

Comment: Hold on a sec - quantum = John Forster? That could be the problem right there. If you have two accounts, you can't use one to act on things you've done with the other. You can ask moderators to merge accounts.

Comment: Nope it's just my display name. No worries I will contact the mods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: For a matrix $X$, the determinant $det(X^H)=\overline{det(X)}$ where the overline indicates complex conjugation.

Examine $det((I\lambda-A)^H)$

Answer (score -1):

Lets say $\lambda_1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ and $\lambda_2$ is an eigenvalue of $A^H$. We have:
$$
Ax = \lambda_1 x
$$
$$
A^Hy = \lambda_2 y
$$
Doing conjugate transpose on both sides of above equation and since $(A^H)^H = A$, we get:
$$
y^HA = \bar\lambda_2 y^H
$$
Multiplying by $x$ to the right on both sides:
$$
y^HAx = \bar\lambda_2 y^Hx
$$
Now using $Ax = \lambda_1 x$ :
$$
y^H \lambda_1 x = \bar\lambda_2 y^Hx
$$
$$
\lambda_1 y^Hx = \bar\lambda_2 y^Hx
$$
This gives us:
$$
\lambda_1 = \bar \lambda_2
$$
or $\lambda_2 = \bar \lambda_1$ i.e the eigenvalues of conjugate transpose of a matrix are conjugates of the eigenvalues of the original matrix.

Comment: This is wrong, as $y^H x$ can be zero.

Comment: Actually, what this proves is that $x , y$ (eigenvector of  the original and eigenvector of the conjugate transponse matrix) are orthogonal, unless they correspond to the same eigenvalue conjugated).  Same as this one https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3436179/312